# 'react-router' does not contain an export named 'browserHistory'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So I'm trying to use `history` in React, but it seems to be moved around a lot. I found this:

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/ab4552d2ea0ec5c0cf3c534bca654a1af3ea0dec/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md

but it just says that `'react-router' does not contain an export named 'browserHistory'.` How can I solve it? Where can I find history? All answers I found were around 1.5 years old.

Comment: What's the version of `react-router` do you use?

Comment: learn more about react-router here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history

Comment: It's 16.4. The newest one

Comment: use react-router-dom if you use react-router in the web

Comment: and import the BrowserRouter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `BrowserRouter`.

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router';
```

`browserHistory` is something that existed in v2/v3 but was rewritten into `BrowserRouter` in v4.
There is a [migration guide here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/90f9bfd0479316480a132bcf3b8b5ccad2ea2454/packages/react-router/docs/guides/migrating.md#the-router) that should help you.

Answer (score 0):

`history Api` has been moved to a separate **[history package](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history)**

In order to create `browserHistory`, you install history like

```
npm install -S history
```

and write

```
import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory"

const browserHistory = createHistory()
export { browserHistory };
```

However in `react-router-v4` an equivalent of `Router` with `browserHistory` is `BrowserRouter`

Answer (score 0):

You no longer have `browserHistory` apparently. So you can do this instead,

```
<Route>
 <Header />
</Route>
```

and you can do

```
function Header(props) {
 // props.history and props.location are available now inside this component
}
```

and then you can do `props.history.push` or whatever if that is what you want to do.

The link you have is for the older version of `react-router` so check out [react-router 4](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/)